# How to show a plain text only on build description in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I want that the user will have the option to edit the build description as a plain text, but I also display some HTML text on the build page.
If i change the **Configure Global Security -> Markup Formatter** to escaped HTML it treats all the data as a plain text.
Is there any way to change the configuration that jenkins will treat **only** the build description as a plain text?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this. The markup formatter selection has global scope.